# My Pythonscript is not able to create a log file

Tags: python, logging

Hi Below is the code using which I am trying to create a log file but I am not able to create a log file:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='s.log', level=logging.INFO,
                    format="%(asctime)s: %(levelname)s -- %(message)s", datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: It should be created! Your same code works for me. Are u calling this script file directly for eg: `python <filename>.py`. Or importing it into some other module? Are u getting any error?

Answer (score 0):

by simply using 'r' than locate where u want to create ur file

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename=r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\s.log')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Zirel23 but it's not working for me.Here is my code:

logging.basicConfig(filename=r'/home/ravi.ranjan/tech-ops/Public/OPS/Report/Lead_Nurturing_Report/s.log', level=logging.INFO,format="%(asctime)s: %(levelname)s -- %(message)s", datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

Comment: make sure to import logging. code could run without the other stuff

import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename=r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\s.log')

Comment: i was running this code on VS Code but than i remembered people were also using this notebook on jupyter but doesnt seem to work on there